# $BG$ the stack, $BG$ the simplicial presheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, simplicial-stuff, stacks

I have a theoretical question about comparing two objects that I have recently come across.

For concreteness, let us work over the category $C$ of schemes over $k$. Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$. One can construct the stack $BG$ as a fibered category in groupoids and as a simplicial scheme $(BG)_n=G^n$ (with certain face and degeneracy maps which I don't specify). What is the precise relation between these two versions of $BG$? Can I obtain one from the other?

I think I might have heard that "the two constructions are equivalent because the simplicial $BG$ has no higher homotopy groups". Does this make sense? How does this implication work?

Any answer that could help me better understand the relation between these two $BG$s is very welcome.

Comment: What you heard is true in the case of $G$ being Abelian. In general, $BG$ can be nontrivial in more than one dimension. For instance, $\pi_nU\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ for $n$ even and trivial otherwise.

Comment: For the main question, perhaps the nerve of the category is homotopy equivalent to the geometric realisation of your simplicial object.

Comment: Any presentation of an algebraic stack $\mathscr X$ as a quotient of a scheme $U$ by an étale equivalence relation $R \rightrightarrows U$ gives rise to a simplicial scheme by taking its "Čech hypercovering": let $X_i$ be the $i$-fold fibre product of $U$ over $\mathscr X$. Any algebraic stack has such a presentation by \[Tag [04T3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04T3)]. It's not clear to me how well-defined this is, let alone whether this is an equivalence onto some subcategory of simplicial schemes.

Comment: @user51223: what is the $U$ in your comment?

Comment: The "simplicial" name for a "Cech hypercovering" is the "0-coskeleton".  More generally, given the first n stages in a simplicial sheaf, there is a "n-coskeleton" functor that is adjoint to the forgetful functor that remembers only the first n stages of a given simplicial object.

Comment: The stack BG in groupoids is presented by the groupoid in schemes with one object and G as the group of automorphisms. You can take the nerve of this internal groupoid to get a simplicial object in schemes, which is the other form of BG. The simplicial scheme presents a higher stack that is the image under the inclusion of ordinary stacks of the first BG.

Comment: @Qfwfq I think that's supposed to be the n-th unitary group U(n).

Comment: @Horstenson Rather $\text{colim } U(n)$. The individual groups $U(n)$ have well-understood homotopy only up to about degree $2n$ by comparison to this colimit, and after that it becomes more complicated.

Comment: @user51223 That has nothing to do with $U$ not being abelian and everything about $G$ being discrete

Comment: @DenisNardin My first comment was rather about a phrase in the question. I think the part that ``$BG$ has no nontrivial homotopy groups other than $\pi_1BG$'' implies that $BG$ is taken to be $K(G,1)$ in this sentence. Now, I am not sure either $U(n)$ or $U$ as in my previous comment are examples of $K(G,1)$, right!

Comment: @user51223 Sorry if I misunderstood, but to be clear $U(n)$ and $U$ are most certainly not $K(G,1)$ (well, except $n=0$ and $n=1$ for silly reasons)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two constructions are not quite equivalent. Let me write $\mathbf BG$ for the stack and $B_\bullet G$ for the simplicial scheme to better distinguish between them. There is a third relevant player, $BG$, which is the presheaf of ∞-groupoids on $C$ presented by $B_\bullet G$.

The precise relation between these three objects is the following:

1. $\mathbf BG$ is the fppf sheafification of $BG$
2. $BG$ is the colimit of the simplicial object $B_\bullet G$
3. $B_\bullet G$ is the Čech nerve (= $0$-coskeleton) of either $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \to \mathbf BG$ or $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \to BG$

In more detail, algebraic stacks over $k$ (in the sense of Artin, say) form a full subcategory of the $2$-category of fppf sheaves of groupoids (classically, "stacks in groupoids") on $C$, which is itself a full subcategory of the ∞-category of presheaves of ∞-groupoids on $C$. Thus, both $\mathbf BG$ and $BG$ live in this ∞-category (in fact they both belong to the subcategory of presheaves of groupoids), and one is the fppf sheafification of the other. The étale sheafification suffices if $G$ is smooth.

The reason $\mathbf BG$ and $BG$ are not the same is that there is a unique homotopy class of map $X\to BG$ from any scheme $X$, but homotopy classes of maps $X\to \mathbf BG$ are in bijection with isomorphism classes of $G$-torsors on $X$. In fact $BG$ is the full subpresheaf of $\mathbf BG$ spanned by the trivial $G$-torsors.

(Added details about 2.) 
$BG$ being the colimit of $B_\bullet G$ is the manner in which simplicial sets give rise to ∞-groupoids. Of course, one must define ∞-groupoids at some point and one way to do that is to start with simplicial sets and invert weak equivalences, so that we have a localization functor {simplicial sets} → {∞-groupoids}. Once higher category theory is set up however, it turns out that this functor is the composition of the inclusion of simplicial sets into simplicial ∞-groupoids and of the colimit over $\Delta^{op}$ functor (this is the standard fact that a simplicial set is canonically the homotopy colimit of itself). In practice this is often a more useful way to think about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am finding it difficult to understand why $BG$ is the colimit of $B_{\bullet}G$. Could you please detail that a little more?